# Non printable regex

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, pcre, spam-prevention, heuristics

I am in need of a regex that will match non printable characters. The reason being is that I have a hailstorm spammer that is abusing my network and is getting past my PCRE based heuristic filter by obfuscating his subjects with non printable characters. Therefore, any text based rules I create are bypassed because there is no match.

For example:

The regular text based subject: **Reduce tech cоsts with clоud cоmputing**

The obfuscated subject:

- Reduce tech cÐ¾sts with clÐ¾ud cÐ¾mputing
- ReduÑe teÑh cÐ¾sts with ÑlÐ¾ud ÑÐ¾mputing
- ReduÑe teÑh Ñosts with Ñloud Ñomputing
- RÐµducÐµ tÐµch cÐ¾sts with ÑlÐ¾ud ÑÐ¾mputing

What I am looking for is a regex that I can modify to match all of the phrases that have been used and build a list of regexes.

Maybe, if I can get a regex that will match the subjects, I can meta them together with other matching header information that will thwart these messages.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you simply throw away any email whose subject line is provided in an UTF8 encoding.  That prevents anything but ISO8859-1 characters, and those you can filter with most 8-bit regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to match.

```
(Reduce|ReduÑe|RÐµducÐµ)\s*(tech|teÑh|tÐµch)\s*
(cÐ¾sts|Ñosts)\s*(with)\s*(clÐ¾ud|ÑlÐ¾ud|Ñloud)\s*
(cÐ¾mputing|ÑÐ¾mputing|Ñomputing)
```

You can add the unique keywords that have been used in the particular group (reduce, tech, etc) and the above regex handles the different combinations of phrases that can be made using the keywords.

For example, above regex restricts 3x3x2x1x3x3 (162 ways) of spamming using given keywords.

**EDIT:** You can use `` [^\w\s."'\/\\=!@#$%^&*(){}\[\]?><,+|`~-]+ `` for checking if subject contains characters that are not printable, and take actions on it. (If you are using this, you might need to add other regexes to handle spam phrases that can be created with printable characters)

[Demo with PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/rN7gP1/1)

Comment: Thank you for that answer but unfortunately the engine that I am using does not allow non typeable characters even in the regex itself. 

Is there another way to create the regex without the actual characters in the regex?